# Terraform Init/apply/destroy - SSL Connection Problems

Tags: ssl, terraform

our company proxy brokes the SSL Connections and the proxy use our own CA.
So i have always tell the applications i use (RubyGems, Python Pip, Azure CLI ...) to use our company CA Certificate.

Does anyone know, how i can use our CA Certificate with a local Terraform installation?

Comment: you added your own answer, not a comment. This is the section you'd add a comment. You can also just do an edit to your original question to provider more details to your question. I have added an edit to my answer for how to properly import a cert into your certificate store on Cent OS so it is always trusted or to have you verify you need the cert for client authentication to the proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

Is the CA deployed to your OS's certificate store or can you import it?  If so, Terraform (and probably other tools) should just be able to work with a proxy like this with no other configuration.  If you need some further direction, tell us what operating system and how you typically access you have to the CA.

Edit:

@Kreikeneka have you have the certain the location CentOS expects to import into the store. There is a command you need to run that actually imports it `update-ca-trust`. Have you run this? If the cert is being used for SSL and you just need to trust it when going through your proxy, that is all you should need to do.  You shouldn't need to tell your tools (Terraform, PIP, etc) to trust it for SSL with the proxy. If the cert is imported into your certificate store, it should be passively usable from any connection on from the machine from any process.

If you are using the cert for client authentication to the proxy then just trusting the cert by placing it in the certificate store probably won't work.

I'm not clear from your comments if you need the cert for SSL or for client authentication to the proxy.  Check with your IT what it is really used for if you aren't sure and get back to us.

> As of CentOS 6+, there is a tool for this. Per this guide,
>   certificates can be installed first by enabling the system shared CA
>   store:
>
> update-ca-trust enable
>
> Then placing the certificates to trust as CA's
>   in /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/ for high priority
>   (non-overridable), or /usr/share/pki/ca-trust-source/ (lower priority,
>   overridable), and finally updating the system store with:
>
> update-ca-trust extract
>
> Et voila, system tools will now trust those
>   certificates when making secure connections!

Source:

https://serverfault.com/questions/511812/how-does-one-install-a-custom-ca-certificate-on-centos

Comment: I wrote at a new comment. Thanks in advance for your help!